# Norm, Spectrum, and Adjoint of an Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

The problem I'm trying to solve reads: Let $\{w_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{\infty}$, and define $T: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$, $T\left(\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\right) = \{w_nx_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Compute $||T||$, $\sigma(T)$, and $T^*$.

So far I've come up with $||T|| = ||\{w_k\}||_{\infty}$ (using the definition of an operator norm) and $\sigma(T) = \{w_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (by computing the inverse of $\lambda I - T$).

I think I'm stuck on the third part, though. I started with $\langle Tx,y \rangle = \langle x,T^*y \rangle$ and got as far as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n(w_n\overline{y_n} - \overline{T^*y_n}) = 0$. But I don't know what to do next.

Am I on the right track? And if not, where did I go wrong? I'm basically teaching myself this material because I've been too sick to go to class, so I'm not sure if I understand it or not.

Comment: From here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337896/norm-of-multiplication-operator-in-ell2-bbb-n-is-x-infty it seems that $\|T\| = \|w\|_\infty$ is correct.

Comment: This question seems to address the spectrum of your given operator: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031388/spectrum-of-lp-multiplication-operator-brezis-6-17

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you! I thought $\{0\}$ seemed too simple; I computed the inverse wrong. Instead of solving $(\lambda S - ST)x = x$ for $S$, I accidentally solved $(\lambda S - T)x = x$. And that's a bit different. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on the third part of the problem some more; here is my proposed solution:

Let $x, y \in \ell^2$.
\begin{align*}
\langle Tx, y \rangle &= \langle x, T^*y \rangle\\
\langle wx,y \rangle &= \langle x, T^*y \rangle\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} w_nx_n\overline{y_n} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\overline{T^*y_n}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (w_nx_n\overline{y_n} - x_n\overline{T^*y_n}) &= 0\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n(w_n\overline{y_n} - \overline{T^*y_n}) &= 0\\
\end{align*}
Note that this equation holds for all $x,y \in \ell^2$; in particular, it holds for $x = \{e_i\}$ for each $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y$ such that only the $i$th term is nonzero. It follows that for each $i$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (w_n\overline{y_n} - \overline{T^*y_n}) &= w_i\overline{y_i} - \overline{(T^*y)_i} =0\\
w_i \overline{y_i} &= \overline{(T^*y)_i}\\
w\overline{y} &= \overline{T^*y}\\
\overline{w}y &= T^*y
\end{align*}